# Trouble getting gammu to identify brovi LTE stick

Tags: raspbian, usb-modeswitch

I have a USB LTE modem "Brovi E3372-325". With that and a Raspberry Pi 4 (latest and fresh Raspbian OS bookworm) I want to use gammu to send and retrieve sms messages.
LTE functuality is currently not needed.

However, `gammu detect` seems not to recognize this modem.

I followed Pavel's excellent guide (https://blog.tanatos.org/posts/huawei_e3372h-325_brovi_with_linux_stickmode/) to switch the modem to stick mode.

Running `mmcli -m 0` works and returns modem information, including information on the system:

```
 System    |               device: /sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2
           |              drivers: option, cdc_ncm
           |               plugin: generic
           |         primary port: ttyUSB1
           |                ports: ttyUSB1 (at), ttyUSB2 (ignored), ttyUSB4 (ignored),
           |                       usb0 (net)
```

Running dmesg returns

```
[    9.868002] usbcore: registered new interface driver option
[    9.868043] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[    9.869796] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    9.869994] option 1-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    9.870146] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    9.870237] option 1-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    9.870348] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[    9.870435] option 1-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    9.870542] option 1-1.2:1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[    9.870647] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[   10.007369] cdc_ncm 1-1.2:1.5: MAC-Address: 5a:d0:6c:f4:22:67
[   10.013166] cdc_ncm 1-1.2:1.5 usb0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2, CDC NCM (NO ZLP), 5a:d0:6c:f4:22:67
[   10.013392] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[   10.021546] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[   10.031318] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_mbim
```

`gammu-detect` lists ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2 and ttyUSB3, however running `gammu identify` it results in timeouts regardless of the port.

I also set ttyUSB1 to be unmanaged by NetworkManager service, which did not help with my problem.

Also, I have firmware version 3.0.2.61 with no available update.

Is there anything else I can check or do?